# What may cause error Platform not found: sensor.ping?

Tags: home-assistant

I am trying to setup a binary icmp sensor to see when my TV is on or off.

I have added this to my configuration.yaml

```
# Sensors
sensor:
 #TCL 
 - platform: ping
   host: 192.168.0.1
```

and I am getting the following error when I try to check the config:

```
Configuration invalid
Platform not found: sensor.ping
```

Version:0.84.6 (HASS.io)

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 4):

Silly me!

It is a binary sensor so it should be:

```
binary_sensor:
#TCL 
  - platform: ping
    host: 192.168.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Binary sensor AND:

```
device_tracker:
  - platform: ping
    hosts:
      xi_readmi7a_name_ping: 192.168.1.43
      ...
```

Platform: ping allows you to create both a binary sensor (on/off) and a device_tracker (home/not_home). Accordingly, device_tracker can be added for stationary location of the user ...